# solr string range query error

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a query in solr:

```
YohohoString:[33333;* TO 3333;2015-02-10+00:00:00]
```

and this one works perfectly !

But:

```
YohohoString:[3333;2015-02-10+00:00:00 TO 33333;*]
```

returns error.

As any possible way exists to resolve this problem. May be my query is so buggy, or any exclude search method exists ?

Comment: Are those supposed to be range queries? I'm not familiar with the `;` separator. What do you intend the queries to do?

Comment: 3333; - is simply astring ! This way data was indexed in the solr: Id;Datatime

Comment: I'm not familiar with using range queries on normal strings. It might be easier to split *Id* and *Datetime* into their own fields.

Comment: What does a sample of your data look like? What do you expect to be returned? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?